# Could not convert IEnumerable of anonymous type to IEnumerable<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, dynamic, anonymous-types

I have an action to search people in a controller, it will return a list of anonymouse:

```
[UnitOfWork]
[HttpGet, Route("api/Search/People")]
public virtual IHttpActionResult GetResult(string keyword)
{
    // ...
    var result = peopleList.Select(x => new
    {
        PersonId = x.Id.Value,
        EmploymentNumber = x.EmploymentNumber,
        FirstName = x.Name.FirstName,
        LastName = x.Name.LastName,
        Email = x.Email
    });
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Below is the test case of the method:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSearchPeople()
{
    // Mocks...
    var target = new PeopleSearchController(searchRepository, personRepository, new FakePermissionProvider());
    // Error here
    var result = (OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>)target.GetResult("Ashley");
    Assert.NotNull(peopleList);
    // Other assert...
}
```

Then I get error as below:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1e`5[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Guid,System.String]]]'
 to type 
'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]]'.
```

It seems IEnumerable with class or single anonymous are OK for such convert, but IEnumerable with anonymous does not works.

How can I do such conversion? thanks.

Comment: maybe `var result = target.GetResult("Ashley") as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<object>>;` works for you in your test method...?

Comment: @stefankmitph `result` will be always null.

Answer (score 2):

You are not casting some to dynamic, but concrete parametrized type to other parametrized type. The problem your code is suffering from is called covariance and contravariance. Unfortunately, `class` doesn't support covariance/contravariance (`class` is always invariant).
Possible workaround:

```
var result = ((dynamic)target).GetResult("Ashley");
//result is of type OkNegotiatedContentResult<...>
var content = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)result.Content;
```

Since `IEnumerable` is covariant, that cast will work.

More about covariance and contravariance [on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You could try with

```
IHttpActionResult result = target.GetResult("Ashley");
IEnumerable<dynamic> content = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)((dynamic)result).Content;
```

You use `dynamic` to use the property `.Content` that will return a `IEnumerable<T>`, and then use covariance to cast it to `IEnumerable<object>`/`IEnumerable<dynamic>` (they are equivalent at the CLR level... `dynamic` is a magic done by the compiler)

Note that this won't work if the `T` of `OkNegotiatedContentResult` is a value type, but in your case it is a reference type, so there aren't problems.

Comment: I also have the similar problem. Your solution works to test the return result. But what if I want to test whether the controller return ```OkNegotiationResult``` or not?

Comment: This should work:  Assert.AreEqual(typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>), result.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());